# CSS/JavaScript: Change element class depending on its' current background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

For a fixed, transparent menu button (in a `position:fixed;` menu) I want to achieve the following:

> - If the button is on a hovering a mostly dark background, make it    white.
> - If the button is hovering a mostly bright background, make it    black.

Sounds simple but seems to be really complicated.

I have found the following library: http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/

Problems:

- only works for images and hardly for background images
- does not work for non-image backgrounds

I have read a lot about CSS Blend modes (https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) however I really can not figure out how they could help me to achieve this simple behaviour.

I also have read that the `canvas` element may help but I do not know why.

This is my dummy code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
     check_bg_for_el();
});

function check_bg_for_el() {
    if(hasDarkBackground($('#myel'))) {
       $(this).addClass('dark-bg');
    }  else {
       $(this).addClass('light-bg');
    }
}

function hasDarkBackground(el) {
    // ????
}
```

Do you have any idea on how this might be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried Window.getComputedStyle?

Comment: @OlegYudovich How may this help me?

Comment: Are you trying to find out if an image is dark or light ? Or how to make  dark image light and the other way around?

Comment: @Blindman67 I want to know: Which is the color behind a transparent div?

Comment: It's not an easy task as you can't sample colors from DOM elements directly. You can get the elements below the cursor using `document.elementsFromPoint` and then parse for image or color using getComputedStyle. If image or gradient you have to sample/average the area using canvas by rebuilding the DOM element into the canvas and then get the colors (much like html2canvas work). You would want to convert that to a luma value combined with a threshold. The simplest approach is to use mix-blending mode "difference" via CSS but that won't give B/W. The question as-is would require a broad answer.

Comment: @K3N Thanks for the useful answer at least it seems that there is no easy way to achieve this. Mix-blending mode would be great if it had functionality like this, but as you stated unfortunatly it has not. I had a look at html2canvas, maybe there is a way using this but there will definitly be problems with a complex website.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a reusable function for you.
You can change any CSS property (passing as arguments using their JS counterpart).
Example CSS `background-color` =>  `backgroundColor`.

Color must be passed in `rgb` format as returned by `window.getComputedStyle()`.

```js
let changeDomCond = (source, target, condProp, condPropValue, newPropValue) => {
  let sourceDom = document.getElementById(source);
  let targetDom = document.getElementById(target);
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(sourceDom);
  if (style[condProp] === condPropValue) {
    targetDom.style[condProp] = newPropValue;
  }
};

  let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', e=> {
    changeDomCond('bkg1', 'a', 'backgroundColor', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgb(100, 100, 200)');

changeDomCond('bkg2', 'b', 'backgroundColor', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)', 'rgb(255, 150, 255)');
  });
```

```css
#bkg1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#bkg2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

#a,
#b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click here to change color conditionally</button>
<div id="bkg1">
  <div id="a">
    Hello 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bkg2">
  <div id="b">
    Hello 2
  </div>
</div>
```